# How can I position a span in the top right of a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, positioning

I have a text area with `id="aboutme"` and an span with `class="maxlength-feedback"`, I want the span to be positioned in the top-right-hand corner of the textarea. It will be a counter for the text area.

I know both elements should have `position="relative"` and the span should be `display="inline-block"`, but it's not working.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just do it like this

Explanation: Wrap your `textarea` inside a container `div` and give `position: relative;` to the container, and `position: absolute;` to `span`, now to be sure your div default behavior which is `display: block;` will make your span flow on the extreme left so use `display: inline-block;` for your container div

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxVPE/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <span>Counter</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrap span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need any display rules when using positioning as it effectively sets the element's display level to block.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks see the difference in this http://jsfiddle.net/bxVPE/ and this http://jsfiddle.net/bxVPE/1/ or else you need to define width, this is a dynamic width approach, flexible

Answer (score 2):

**Html**

```
<div>
    <span class="mySpan">Some Text</span>
    <textarea class="myTextArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}

.mySpan{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VSWXs/

Answer (score 1):

no, maxlength-feedback has to be `absolute` positioned, like this;

```
#aboutme {
 position:relative;
}

.maxlength-feedback {
position:absolute;
right: 0; /* or so */
top: 0; /* or so */
}
```